# calculate the time when HTTP session expires

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, session, filter

I have a backend application and UI application that communicate via REST. I want to provide UI the ability to check if session expired or not - if it is expired than UI will show a dialog window.

The idea is to set cookie on every request with the expiration time of session, then UI will start timer and when the current time will be the same as expiration time, it will show the session expire window.

For this, I have implement the filter

```
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
            if (null != session) {
                Cookie sessionExpireTime = new Cookie("SESSION_EXPIRE_TIME", "?????");
                sessionExpireTime.setSecure(true);
                sessionExpireTime.setHttpOnly(true);
                httpServletResponse.addCookie(sessionExpireTime);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        }
    };
```

But how to set the expiration time of the session?

Comment: why not just set a unix timecode, and then have another filter that gets the property, looks at what time it is checks the cookie unix time and if the diff is greater than a certain value its invalid.

Comment: the thing is UI needs to show the dialog itself - backend being REST cannot notify about expired session without server push or long polling.